# Let $F$ be a field in which $1+1=0$. Prove that for any $x \in F$, we have $x=-x$ (i.e. any element in F equals its own negative.)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field in which $1+1=0$. Prove that for any $x \in F$, we have $x=-x$ (i.e.) any element in F equals its own negative.

No idea how to prove this, I am guessing I would start with 1+1=0 and derive the proof of x=-x from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's $(1+1)x$?  Can you do some algebra on that?